# MySQL Error message with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

My error message is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'auto'' at line 5

My query is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\file.csv'
INTO TABLE `tableName`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY 'auto'
```

I'm running the query via php function mysql_query();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the query sees an unclosed single quote after defining the escape sequence.

```
 ESCAPED BY '\' <-- unclosed quote!
```

By default, MySQL uses a backslash as the escape character. If you wish to be explicit, I believe you will need to use a double-backslash:

```
 ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

Then, remove the quotes around `'auto'`.

Answer (score 0):

try putting auto out of ''

```
LINES TERMINATED BY auto
```

or use

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: Are you sure `LINES TERMINATED BY auto` does work?! It generates error.